# How do I make an entire <li> element a link?

Tags: html, css

So I have a bunch of tabs that are all inside of a list element. I'm using Ruby on Rails in the View, so it looks something like this:

```
<div id="top-nav">
    <ul>
        <li> <%= link_to "Home", user_root_path() %> </li>
        <li> <%= link_to "Manage", manage_path() %> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And so on.

How do I style it in CSS so that I can click on the box around the text to go to that link, instead of having to click on the text itself?

I looked at some answers and tried using display:block; inside the top-nav and li element, but it hasn't been working.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no connection with Ruby on Rails, it's only html/css issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the following:

```
 - <li> tag should have ZERO padding
 - <a> tag should have ZERO margin
 - <a> tag should have the actual padding
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea in the wrong place. Try styling your link to be `display:block`, ex:

```
#top-nav a:link {
    display: block;
    /* padding, etc... */
}
```